# Export & Import custom field data with customer CSV file in magento

Tags: magento

I got a requirement to add a extra field(custom filed to store some ID) to customers CSV file. 
means i will add a extra column to customers table. 
how to import & export that column data with customers.csv file.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add extras field in customer export csv then look into this file.
app\code\core\Mage\Customer\Model\Convert\Parser/Customer.php
and add your extra field in this file